# what should I do to async initial some data in flutter before the page load

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am writing a simeple todo list app, the todo item stored in sqlite
`sqflite: ^2.0.0+3` right now. I want to load the sqlite todo data before loading the flutter page, this is my initial code looks like in flutter:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  GlobalKey _inputViewKey = GlobalKey();
  List<Todo> _todos = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    var _db = DBProvider.db;
    _todos = await _db.getAllTodo();
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

and this is the function to load data from database:

```
 Future<List<Todo>> getAllTodo() async {
    final db = await database;
    var result = await db.query('Todo');
    return result.map((it) => Todo.fromJson(it)).toList();
  }
```

the IDE told that I should add async in the initial function. When I add the async function, the initial function could not work. What should I do to make it work? how to initial the async data before the HomePage?

Comment: Inside init() method use SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {} And inside curly braces of SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) call your data fetching methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant mark async on inistate. You can try this

```dart
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  GlobalKey _inputViewKey = GlobalKey();
  List<Todo> _todos = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
var _db = DBProvider.db;
getAllTodo();
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

And in the method

```dart
getAllTodo() async {
    final db = await database;
    var result = await db.query('Todo');
    _todos = result.map((it) => Todo.fromJson(it)).toList();
  setState((){});
  }
```